# Dependent Dropdown list. Filtering from one list to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I having an issue passing the return parameters to the second dropdown list. Second list is completely dependent on the selection from the first one. I'm pretty sure the SP is fine. Again, my issue is passing the value.

Stored Procedure

```
  PROCEDURE ev_dropdown(
      cur_out    IN OUT   eqpack.t_cur_out,
      p_result   OUT      VARCHAR2,
      p_reference_id  IN NUMBER
   )

   IS
   BEGIN
      OPEN cur_out FOR

         SELECT ev_id, ev


           FROM event WHERE a_ref = p_reference_id;



   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         p_result :=
                   'An error occurred in get_events_dropdown - ' || SQLERRM;

   END ev_dropdown;
```

.cs

```
 public void populateSpecificEv(int p)
        {

            DataTable dtRef = CreateReferenceDT();
            string conn = GetConnectString();
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(conn))
            using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "eqpackage.get_events_dropdown";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.Parameters["p_reference_id"].Value = p;

                OracleDataReader reader;
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                dtRef.Rows.Add("0", "-select-");


                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    dtRef.Rows.Add(reader[0], reader[1]);

                }

                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                command.Connection.Close();
                command.Connection.Dispose();
                return dtRef; //Error -returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression  


            }
          }

        DataTable CreateReferenceDT()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

            return dt;

        }
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void ddlSys_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int p = int.Parse(ddlSystems.SelectedItem.Value);
    dbase.populateSpecificEvent(p);

    DataTable dt1 = dbase.PopulateEvDropDown();
    ddlEv.DataSource = dt1;
    ddlEv.DataTextField = "name";
    ddlEv.DataValueField = "id";
    ddlEv.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to update your stored procedure to actually just perform a SELECT statement without explicitly creating its own cursor.  You would then call [command.ExecuteQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc093a69.aspx) (which I see you are doing), which would return an [IDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader), which is basically a forward-only, read-only cursor.

I would remove the following extra lines:

```
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.Connection.Close();
command.Connection.Dispose();
```

If you change your stored procedure to actually just be a select statement, then you can use your `while(reader.Read())` loop to read in the rows, one at a time, and insert them into your `DataTable`, or simply call [DataTable.Load(IDataReader)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb).